# Facebook-Graph-API get post by post id

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm having problem fetching post by post id using Graph API. 
In Graph API reference (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/post/) it says that:

> Querying without the read_stream permission will return only the public view of the data (i.e. data that can be see when the user is logged out).

I'm able to open https://www.facebook.com/franzee/posts/10151947780174121 without logging in to Facebook, but when I try to access this post using Graph API or Graph API Explorer I get the following error

```
{
    "error": {
        "message": "Unsupported get request.", 
        "type": "GraphMethodException", 
        "code": 100
    }
}
```

I am using valid token and Graph API call, and I'm getting results when fetching single posts from group or public page. Why is then error message returned when I try to fetch post by post id even though the post is visible when I'm logged out?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't access a user's posts without a user access token from a user who can see the posts - even if a post is marked as 'Public', that means Public to Facebook users, not completely public via the web and API - You still need to provide the access token of the Facebook user you're fetching the posts on behalf of

Comment: Is it valid that I use FB application access token instead of user access token for accessing user's post?

Comment: If it's working for you, sure, but typically you'll need a user access token to access user content

Comment: It's not working, that is why I'm asking. With the app access token I can access public posts for groups and public pages, but not user's public posts.

Comment: Yes, you can't access a user's posts without a user access token from a user who can see the posts

Comment: Authorised Data resellers like Datasift and GNIP can give you this level of information, but at a cost.

Comment: As far as I know there's no such thing as an 'Authorised' data reseller - selling of data from the Facebook API is expressly forbidden: https://developers.facebook.com/policy